# Issue sending email via Mandrill

Tags: emails, mandrill

I've set up a site to send emails via Mandrill over SMTP.
However, this does not seem to be sending emails.

If I test the email config it says a message has been sent but the email is not received and there is no record of the email in the Mandrill Outbound messages.

Sending over SSL (which has worked on other Craft sites on same host) on port 465.

Suggestions appreciated as client not receiving messages through the site.

Cole

Comment: To add some further information/context to this, the site is running on HTTPS but would assume that this wouldn't make a difference to whether Craft can or cannot connect to Mandrill.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm on the same boat ... Check out http://status.mandrillapp.com . Your issues are, more than likely, due to Mandrill currently being down and having issues (for the past couple days now).